# Motorizing Crocodile Locomotive set 10277 - are there any sets that include hub & motor I need?

Tags: technic, trains, powered-up

Crocodile Locomotive can be powered up by using 1 x [88009](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/hub-88009) and 1 x [88013](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/technic-large-motor-88013). Reviews on hubs and motors strongly suggest it is better, financially, to buy them as part of the sets, not separately.

Is there any set that contains both of these? And how to find it? If there is none, sets that contains only one or the other would be appreciated.

Additional criteria for the "goodness" of answer:

- Generic train, Technic or Powered Up parts, as I'd be buying it for the parts, not the model.
- Low price, or low price per brick (prices may change but relation between prices seems roughly constant for sets in production)
- Set is available now, as of middle of 2021, to buy new from The LEGO Group

Comment: Consider making use of the secondary market (bricklink et al) - both these (in new condition) can be obtained there for about half what LEGO is charging for them currently. Make sure to look for the items themselves though ([bb0892c01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0892c01&idColor=1#T=P&C=1) and [bb0959c01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0959c01&idColor=85#T=P&C=85))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These parts are not found in the same set at this time, but there may still be an adequate solution.

This is a good question for Bricklink.  In Bricklink terms the numbers you listed are for the "sets" that include these individual parts.  The parts you are looking for are included in sets other than the set just for the part.  The [L-Motor appears in eight](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=bb0959c01&in=S) other sets and the [Train hub appears in five](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=bb0892c01&in=S) different sets (numbers are valid by the time of this answer).

Based on that we can only conclude that these parts are not in the same set at this point, but that doesn't have to be the only conclusion.  The [list of sets with the hub](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=bb0892c01&in=S) includes three train sets.  For instance, the [60198 Cargo Train](https://brickset.com/sets/60198-1/Cargo-Train) is still available directly from LEGO and includes the [train motor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0896c01&idColor=11#T=P&C=11).  The train motor seems like an easier way to power your train.  The [60197 Passenger Train](https://brickset.com/sets/60197-1/Passenger-Train) is also still available, and it is cheaper.  The Disney Train is still available, but it is the most expensive.

Comment: Am I getting this rigth? Are you suggesting that I buy a cargo train and build a cargo wagon with hub and engine from that set, and then use it to pretend my crocodile is pulling it, when it fact it'll be pushing the locomotive?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting for you to buy one of the train sets for the two parts in question.  That seemed to be what the question was about.  The rest of the parts are hopefully useful to you for something else.  It may also be cheaper for you to just buy the two parts you are looking for.

Comment: but there is no way to rebuild Crocodile to use the train motor. Way too many things won't fit.

Comment: Then it sounds like you should get the parts you want from LEGO directly or a bricklink seller and not worry about getting them in a set.  But if you want them in a set you can use the links above to see which sets those could be.  There aren't many and most of them are still on sale by TLG.